# CSS table cell which has image in the middle and then text at the of the cell bottom

Tags: css, wordpress, image, html-table

I have been struggling to find a simple solution to the following problem using the CSS inline styles due to being on a free wordpress.com blog.

a table

inside each table cell there is an three parts

a hyperlink to enclose the two objects below
image - align vertical and horizontally centred in the table cell
text at the bottom of the table cell

```
<psedo markup>

<td>
  <a href="#">
   <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="" />
   <p style="vertical-align:bottom">Text at the bottom</p>
  </a>
```

but just cant seem to get a consistent result, am I better using `<div style="display:block">` instead?

Comment: If your purpose was to vertically align the image in the `<td>` element than you want the `<td>` tag to have `vertical-align: middle;` not the `<img>` tag itself.

Comment: Right, although tables cells already default to `vertical-align: middle;`

Answer (score 1):

If you can use html5, use a `figure`:

```
<td>
    <a href="http://gravatar.com">
        <figure style="text-align: center;">
             <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5a25eba05dc8ac4384384c7a220958a6?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG&amp;f=1" 
                  alt="" width="32" height="32">
             <figcaption>gravatar glyph</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
</td>
```

The `figure` element was added precisely for situations like this, though the needed style here is a bit quirky.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;"> 
            <a>link</a>
            <img style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" src="http://placebacn.com/400/300">
            <p>Bacon... Bacon... Bacon...</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Even if you can't add a CSS file you may be able to add a `<style>` block before the HTML which would be better than inline styles:

```
<style>
    td {
        text-align: center;
    }
    td img {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;  
    }
</style>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xeTPx/2/

Please don't use tables for layout (i.e. non-tabular data - not sure if this is or not), there are other ways to have a similar layout without the bloated markup and accessibility problems. `display: flex` is often a good option as it now has support in a lot of today's browsers. Sometimes even using other markup with CSS `display: table` and `display: table-cell` is another option.

This might be a good read on `vertical-align`: http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to separate img and text from the same alignment-structure. I think you can manage to center the img but the text ruins this alignment. The trick that I use is position>relative to the parent and position>absolute to the child. Here you go:

```
<td>
    <a href="#" style='**position:relative;**'>
        <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="" />
        <p style="**position:absolute; bottom:0;**">Text at the bottom</p>
    </a>
</td>
```

By doing this p is not in the same alignment structure anymore.
I hope this solves your problem.